# Creating two more users when a user successfully sign up - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a new User with Firebase and it is working fine.

What i want is to create another two more users when this 1st user successfully signs up. I am trying this but it is giving me error.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            if (role.equals("Supplier")) {

           //.....Here i am creating another user......//

                                FirebaseAuth mAuth1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                                mAuth1.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                } else {
                                                    Log.w("TAG", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                                                    Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this,
                                                            "An Error has occurred...\nPlease try Again Later",
                                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }

                                            }   
                                        });
                                     }
       .........
```

I am getting error on creation of 2nd user that is:

[image: error image]

How can i resolve this?

Comment: the `this` object being passed inside the mAuth1...addOnCompleteListener is incorrect. Check that the object should be an activity context.